# Subsetting data frame based on certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like

```
set.seed(101)
f=data.frame(a=sample(1:5), b=sample(1:5), c=sample(1:5))
```

I want to remove all the rows and cols where there is value greater than 3.
Since other row/col contain value greater than 3 they will be removed.

So the output will be only

```
1 3 3
```

I could subset on rows and cols individually and then do it.

Comment: i meant could. i was thinking on lines of rowsums but could not get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
f[rowSums(f > 3) == 0, ]

#  a b c
#1 1 1 3
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can use `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
f %>% filter_all(all_vars(. <= 3))
```

Comment: thanks seems so simple now

Answer (score 1):

```
#Subset for all values <=3 (AND Condition)
f <- subset.data.frame(f, a <= 3 & b <= 3 & c <= 3)

#Subset for min one value <=3 (OR Condition)
f <- subset.data.frame(f, a <= 3 | b <= 3 | c <= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
library(tidyverse)

f %>% filter((a <= 3) & (b <= 3) & (c <= 3))
```

see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html for reference